# How to change language tooltip of the buttons?

Tags: tinymce, toolbar

I need to change the language of the tooltip in buttons of the toolbar in Tinymce.

In this moment is english..

I have tried change the language but only get change in spellchecker

Answer (score 1):

The language packs for TinyMCE are downloaded from a separate web page:

http://archive.tinymce.com/i18n/

This will allow you to grab the languages you need and then deploy them within TinyMCE.  Once you download the zip files you will need to unzip the contents to your tinymce/langs folder and set the language in your TinyMCE init such as:

`language: 'es'`